# AngularJS deregister event listener in dynamically loaded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamically loaded directive that listens for an event from its parent. What happens is this event is getting handled twice inside the directive even though the parent only broadcasts the event once. This event is getting listened to multiple times and I'm not sure where to clean this up.

Here is the Plunker example. You can trigger the parent event by clicking the "Parent Click" button and the handler prints text using console.log(). You will see that the console.log is getting executed twice.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aPiMO2PKDybsZ4cS7Fnh?p=info

Here is my script:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myAppModule.controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.directiveId = 'my-directive1';
    $scope.directiveData = 'Directive 1 data.';

    $scope.parentClick = function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("parentEvent", "hello from parent");
    }
  });

  myAppModule.directive('loaddirective', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        loaddirective: "=",
        directivedata: "="
      },
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        console.log('loaddirective link');
        var value = $scope.loaddirective;

        function update(value) {
          $element.html("<div " + value + " directivedata='directivedata'></div>");
          $compile($element.contents())($scope);
        }
        if (value) {
          update(value);
        }
        $scope.$watch('loaddirective', update);
      },
      controller: ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          console.log('loaddirective controller');
        }
      ]
    };
  });

  myAppModule.directive('myDirective1', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'my-directive1.html',
      scope: {
        directivedata: "="
      },
      controller: ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          var offParentEvent = $scope.$on('parentEvent', function(event, arg) {

            // This event is getting handled twice here. 
            // This is due to my $watch in the 'loaddirective'
            // directive. I need this watch to be able to 
            // dynamically change this directive later.
            // My guess is I need to deregister this by
            // calling offParentEvent() somewhere but I don't
            // know where to do that.

            console.log('myDirective1 parentEvent data: ' + arg);

          });
        }
      ]
    };
  });

})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Why do you need to manually invoke `update` with `if (value) { update(value) }` - this is your second (rather first) call, but it is unnecessary in light of  `$watch`

Comment: I didn't know $watch was immediately invoking update. Removing that if statement you mentioned fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: You still need to make sure to do `element.on("$destroy", ...` to detach the listener of the old element in case `loaddirective` changes and a new element is created